# How can I replace Hash Id of mongodb to simple Int?

Tags: mongodb

Guys I just wanna ask if I can replace the hash ID in MongoDB with a simple index number that iterates each time a user is added.

Instead of this..

```
_id:6156c39a5dbd5784f8561bf3
```

I want it to be replaced with a simple int that iterates each time a user is added to the database

```
_id:1
_id:2
```

and so on..

Comment: It's not a hash, btw. And no, you can't configure mongodb to use auto-incrementing integer ids. You're free to supply your own ids, however. Just be prepared to deal with conflicts, etc.

Comment: Mongo really dislikes its built-in _id to be tampered with. Use your own custom id field instead.

Comment: @JeremyThille: does it really? I haven't noticed this in my experience. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, try to define a custom _id in your Mongoose schema and a recent MongoDB version, and you'll get the following message : `mongoose: Cannot specify a custom index on '_id' for model name [modelName], MongoDB does not allow overwriting the default '_id' index. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-id-index`

Comment: @JeremyThille: sounds like mongoose's fault (or incorrect usage of it) for trying to overwrite the index. You absolutely can use whatever values for the _id field (except for arrays). It's in the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/

Comment: Yes, I used to overwrite the default _id with [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) but I stopped doing that. Now I just leave _id alone and I define my own custom short id fields. The fact that you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: "The fact that you can doesn't mean you should." - naturally. That's not what we were discussing, though. Anyhow, I think the OP has enough info in this thread.

Comment: @JeremyThille

Thank you guys two, the reason why I want to do the id to be simple, because we have a project that needed to use algo, and even before they announce it. I was focusing really hard in MERN and I got stuck on how I can implement the algo with the objectID. That is why I need the index.

I don't know if it's going to work, but I'll try for the name instead. Hope you can give advice for me

Comment: You can set your own value for `_id`. MongoDB creates the field automatically if not provided. You cannot modify the value of the `_id` field. What is your intention? The generated `ObjectId` is a combination of insert-time + machine-identifier + process id + sequential number. You can use it also for sorting.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit. My intention is, I am going to create an online shop-like, and categorize and using a merge algorithm. The reason why I want to create a custom id is so I can show the codes to them instead of using the built it function for mongoose. 

So each time I add a new item. the id will increment on its own like stated above